# Binding EditTextPreference to a given preference file (getSharedPreferences)

Tags: android, file, redirect, preferenceactivity

two activities here, A and B. A is main, B is PreferenceActivity with two EditTextPreference.

I want to be able to access the preferences generated by B from activity A, and for that I need of course (I guess) getSharedPreferences on A. But in order to do that I need to supply the preference file for the activity that generated it. This is tedious (long names), erratic at best (depends on the activity that generated it), and finally it's a mess, because it's much better to keep everything under one xml file, with a name that is well known to all my activities. And besides, if I have 100 activities, how would I keep track of preference files anyway...

So the point is: **how do I "bind" an EditTextPreference in a way that the changes are made to a given preference file, not the one automatically generated by Android**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you want to use a specific preferences file. Why not the default one?

`SharedPreferences pm = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` gives you the shared preferences that are valid all across your application. What was written in your PreferenceActivity will be in there.

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you. I was trying getPreferences and getSharedPreferences and neither worked. The first would give me different file names (depending on the activity I was in) and to use the second I needed to know in advance the full package+class name (which is the file name), and it wouldn't work for different preferences activities, that would generate prefs automatically according to each EditTextPreferences.

Comment: Glad to help! Could I ask you to accept the answer? That way we both get rep points. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the green tick the way to do that? I'm really confused, I'm new here. If you mean vote up, I tried, but I don't have enough rep. Ah, and you are the author of EboBirthday, right? Wow...

Comment: No, the green tick is fine! (It wasn't accepted yet when I wrote the comment, that's why I asked. Sorry, didn't mean to push you :) it's common for first-time posters to not know about this whole accepting answer business, so I just wanted to point it out.)

Answer (score 0):

Use a static string in one of your classes

Comment: I tried that using getSharedPreferences. It would work for me, considering that I used EditTextPreferences from only one PreferenceActivity. That way I could know the package+class name and access statically from all others. However, it's not the most elegant, considering I could add other PreferenceActivity'ies later, and each EditTextPreference change settings to their own activity preference file. It would only increase complexity... I was ending with a bunch of "package_activityname.xml" files that way, and needed to remember each. Anyway, thank you very much for helping me! :-)

Comment: Wait, do you want preferences for individual activities? It's really confusing what you want exactly.

Comment: I have only one PreferenceActivity, and I don't need individual files, even though there is one for each PreferenceActivity. I just wanted to know if there was a way to access ALL preferences from all activities in a centralized way, without needing to know the name of each generated xml file (under /data/data/package/shared_prefs). I didn't know that even existed, so I asked if I could, *at least*, redirect the EditTextPreferences to a previously known xml file.